# A specific DAG stops running in Airflow, even when the scheduler is running fine

Tags: python, mysql, airflow

My question is about a DAG that stops executing tasks, even though the scheduler appears to be running fine. I am running a remote Airflow server, version 1.8.0 on an Ubuntu EC2 instance. The scheduler is running `LocalExecutor`. I start the scheduler with `airflow scheduler -D` and everything seems to be working fine. All jobs execute dependably and externally trigger jobs triggered via an API call are working fine.

My one glaring exception is that I have a job that we use to process site visit data that keeps on choking. Specifically, what happens it that the job says that it is running, but nothing is sent to the queue and no tasks actually run. In the UI, it just gets stuck in a status that look like this:

[image]

A few tasks execute, the rest just get stuck in the queue, and the DAG lists itself a "running" indefinitely. What's puzzling, though, is that when I check system activity with `htop` the scheduler seems to be actively processing the task queue:

[image]

"Out_of_Aurum_Task_X" indicate a task from the current DAG run. We can see from the task inventory, however, that these tasks are just stuck in "queued" without actually running: 
[image]

I have checked `/logs` and everything looks good. There are no errors or warning popping up in either specific task logs or in `airflow-scheduler.log`

I'm stumped. What's breaking my DAG and how can I fix it? In case this information is relevant, I am connecting to MySQL DBs via a combination of MySQL hooks from airflow and connections defined within some custom classes using `sqlalchemy`. If I repeatedly close and restart the scheduler eventually the job completes, but obviously this isn't ideal behavior. Is this a meta data issue? Should I follow the steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46183054/airflow-dag-not-getting-scheduled) to wipe out and re-start the metaDB?

**UPDATE**

I started killing ghost processes one at time with `kill -9 PID`. As I was doing this I noticed that a whole bunch of fresh processes appeared, and indeed the DAG started to run again. Just another piece of information.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, we had similar problems until we updated to 1.9.0. Note that for 1.9 and onwards you will need to `pip install "apache-airflow>=1.9.0"` (instead of just `airflow`).  The scheduler has some significant improvements there.  I highly recommend you upgrade.  You'll need to adjust your logging as logging has changed in that version, but we've found it significantly more stable and the most stable version to date (since 1.6.x).

Comment: awesome, sounds like a plan. In that case what I will likely do is rebuild the entire airflow server from scratch with 1.9. Bear with me for a week or so. If that fixes the problem I will come back here and give you the upvote this answer deserves.

Comment: Pointers on the v1.9 install? pip3 install v1.8 by default. I get this:  `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement airflow[mysql,postgres,s3]==1.9 (from versions: 0.1, 0.2.1, 0.2.2, 0.2.3, 0.3, 0.3.1, 0.3.2, 0.4.1, 0.4.2, 0.4.3, 0.4.5, 0.4.6, 0.5.0, 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.2.0, 1.3.0, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.5.2, 1.6.0, 1.6.1, 1.6.2, 1.7.0, 1.7.1.2, 1.7.1.3, 1.8.0)
No matching distribution found for airflow[mysql,postgres,s3]==1.9`

Comment: Nvmnd, got it. And yes, this seems to be the right answer. Much smoother now.

Comment: Actually no, I checked the server this morning and same issue. DAG just unexpectedly shuts down without any informative error output. #frustrated.